# No video output besides with HDMI - No mirror display arrangement

Tags: nvidia, display, dell, hdmi, xrandr

[Ubuntu 21.10]

I'm having a recurring issue where:

When I boot, there is video output on my machine (boots per usual). After boot sequence, there is no video output on my machine. Only with the use of an external monitor via HDMI am I able to log in. Nvidia x server shows there's no other display to be configured (besides my external monitor via HDMI).

nvidia x server and display settings:

[image: Screenshot 1]

After running xrandr command, no other display is detected:

[image: xrandr command screenshot]

<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> does nothing.

All drivers and software are up to date. I have tried unplugging HDMI, shutting down, and restarting to no avail. I'm unsure whether a past update got rid of the Display Mode(s), since I don't see it within Settings anymore. I do remember being able to use my machine without an external monitor, trouble free until I took my laptop home for work, and was unable to detect video output.

I'm not well versed with Ubuntu. Any help would be greatly appreciated - Cheers!

**~ EDIT ~**

Output from `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07) 
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07) 
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07) 
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31) – 
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31) 
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31) 
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f1) 
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1) – 
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1) 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation CM236 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31) 
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31) 
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31) 
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31) – 
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM (rev 31) 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GLM [Quadro M2000M] (rev a2) 01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 High Definition Audio Controller [GeForce 940MX] (rev a1) 
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a) 
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Comment: What does `lspci` command show?

Comment: I just made an edit which adds the output to your Question in a readable way. Once (or if) it is added, would you mind deleting it from the comments. Down here, it may distract viewers away from your question... Its my fault. I usually specify "update question with output" or something similar, but this time. I must have spaced it. Thanks, and my apologies.

Comment: What happens when you run the command `xrandr --auto`?

Comment: @NateT that command does not seem to have any output on my end